# Cyclic group generator and multiplicative identity of correspondng ring

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, cyclic-groups

Can cyclic groups made into ring with unity such that multiplicative identity is not any generator? (Or does there exist example of one such cyclic group?)

Can we make $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ into ring with unity without $+1$ or $-1$ (belonging to $\mathbb{Z}$) as multiplicative identiy.

Motivation: In rings with unity, characteristic  of ring is order of multiplicative identity. Does it has some relation with generator of additive group if it is cyclic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $R = \mathbb Z$, let $\times$ denote the usual multiplication on $\mathbb Z$, and $\odot$ some other multiplication. Suppose $\odot$ has multiplicative identity $k$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
1 = k\odot 1 &= \overbrace{(1+\cdots + 1)}^{k \text{ times}}\odot 1\\
& = \overbrace{1\odot 1 + \cdots + 1\odot 1}^{k \text{ times}} &&\text{by distributivity}\\
&= k\times(1\odot 1)&&\text{by definition}
\end{align}
$$

So we must have $1\odot 1 = \frac 1k$, whence $k = \pm 1$, since $\frac 1k$ must be an integer.

---

For $R = \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, the same argument shows that

$$ k\times(1\odot 1) \equiv 1 \pmod n$$ so $k$ must be invertible modulo $n$. So $k$ is coprime to $n$, and hence it generates the cyclic group.